# How can I check if a function already exists in the SPL stack?

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register

I am trying to use `spl_autoload_register` and I want to create an `if()` statement that will check if the class method as already been registered.

For example:

```
if (spl_autoload_function(array($this, '_loadClass'))
    // Then do nothing
else
    // Then run spl_autoload_register(array($this, '_loadClass));
```

Is something like the above code/method possible?

Comment: Maybe something like this? if (defined('foo')) { 
... 
}

Comment: i thought defined was related to definitions not classes hmmm, but i want to really check if its in the SPL stack not if the function has been defined.

Comment: and a flash it could work inside the class or outside if its loaded = true

Comment: What do you mean by `the SPL stack`? The SplStack class?

Comment: yes, I want to check if a class method has already been loaded

Comment: @Eli if its `SplStack` class change your  title accordingly

Comment: @Shiplu He is not asking about `SplStack` at all, actually.  @Eli should not have answered yes.

Comment: well in my defense i didn't know the difference

Comment: @Levi I was also thinking that.

Comment: FYI: Calling `class_exists` will trigger the autoloader if the class is not already loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to do an autoloader and I want to create an if statement that will check if the class method as already been registered.

You shouldn't. There is no need to do the if statement; `spl_autoload_register` will just ignore a second call with the same arguments:

```
<?php

$foo = function( $class ) {
    return false;
};

spl_autoload_register( $foo );
var_dump( spl_autoload_functions( ) );

spl_autoload_register( $foo );
var_dump( spl_autoload_functions( ) );
```

The output shows that although we called `spl_autoload_register` twice, there is still just *one* autoloader;

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(Closure)#1 (1) {
    ["parameter"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["$class"]=>
      string(10) "<required>"
    }
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(Closure)#1 (1) {
    ["parameter"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["$class"]=>
      string(10) "<required>"
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to make sure a class doesn't register itself twice, you can of course set that in some kind of static member;

```
<?php
class Foo {
    protected static $registered = false;

    public function register( ) {
        if( self::$registered !== false ) {
            return;
        }
        echo "spl_autoload_register( \$this, '_loadClass' );\n";
        self::$registered = true;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo( );
$foo->register( );

$bar = new Foo( );
$bar->register( );
```

The output is obviously one line:

```
spl_autoload_register( $this, '_loadClass' );
```

That said, why are you writing your own autoloader? There are numerous out there already, it's hard to believe that none of them fit your requirements.

Comment: learning experience, we can't all polish our PHP skills by just using other peoples code =)

Comment: Fair enough, learning is actually a very valid answer to the question :)

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer:* I'm not fully confident I understood your question, but I'm confident enough I thought I'd try to answer.

---

There is no `spl_*` function to do this.  The closest you get is `spl_autoload_functions()` which returns the functions that the spl uses to load, not the functions being loaded.

**Solution:**

Write your own loader that logs when a function/class has been loaded and register it with `spl_autoload_register`.

---

**To answer comment:** If you have a class that loads functions, have it append to an internal array of classes it has already loaded.

```
class Autoloader {

    protected $loaded = array();

    function autoload($class) {
        // find class location
        // if it is found:
        // include class
        $this->loaded[] = $class;
    }

    function hasLoaded($class) {
        return in_array($class, $this->loaded);
    }

}

$autoloader = new Autoloader();
spl_autoload_register(array($autloader, 'autoload'));
```

If you don't care to know if it was loaded by the autoloader, you can simply check for existence using [`class_exists`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php).

Comment: i have made an autoloader that loads my classes, but i want to check if a class has been loaded or not. by doing so I have used the spl_autoload_register already

Comment: hmmm, if i use the `spl_autoload_register` internally, will this effect the autoloading process if i specify `class_exists(__CLASS__)`?

Comment: Using `class_exists` does not trigger the autoloader.

Comment: if you want to check if the class exists without having it loaded, use `class_exists('FooClass', false);` - see http://php.net/class_exists

Comment: `class_exists(__CLASS__)` makes no sense at all. for __CLASS__ to be populated, you have to be inside a class method/function. For that to happen, the class must be loaded. Also note that __CLASS__ is not resolved to the extending class in OOP, but always is exactly the class it was put into.

Comment: the issue is that my class autoloader runs twice, when i call my register() method, so in order to stop it from re autoloading the class i want to see if it already in the spl stack.